# Vb.net webapi file download troubles

Tags: vb.net, download, asp.net-web-api

We've been using an IIS filehandler to download files that are stored in a database such as PowerPoint. Now we're trying to switch to webapi. File uploads are working fine but downloads are not.

Using the filehandler the url is like: http://localhost:57851/docmgr?id=6202 which returns a valid file with the following info from Fiddler:
[image: filehandler]

Using the same code in a webapi controller having a url of: http://localhost:57851/webapi/file/GetFile?id=6202 returns a file with additional bytes added. Fiddler data:
[image: webapi]

Note the change in content-type as well even though the content-type is expressly set to "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint".

I must be missing something....

Here is the controller code:

```
<HttpGet>
Public Function GetFile()
    Dim dbConn As New SqlConnection(DigsConnStr)
    Dim dbCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dbRdr As SqlDataReader
    Dim id As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("id")
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    Dim contentType As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileExt As String

    Try
        dbConn.Open()
        dbCmd.Connection = dbConn
        dbCmd.CommandText = "GET_FileForDownload"
        dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VirtualFileRecID", id)
        dbRdr = dbCmd.ExecuteReader
        dbRdr.Read()
        contentType = dbRdr("ContentType")
        bytes = dbRdr("FileBytes")
        fileExt = dbRdr("FileExtension")
        If contentType <> "" Then
            fileName = dbRdr("Title") & fileExt
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
            'HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()

        End If
        dbConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        dbConn.Close()
    Finally
        If Not (dbConn Is Nothing) Then dbConn.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAPI is going to wrap your response in XML (or whatever formatter you have in your webapiconfig class)

You really shouldn't access the response stream directly with WebAPI but you can return a HttpResponseMessage object with the file stream

Check this out

```
<HTTPGET>
Public Function GetFile(FileID as Integer) As HttpResponseMessage
 Dim path = "C:\Temp\test.exe"
 Dim result As New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
 Dim stream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)

 result.Content = New StreamContent(stream)
 result.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream")

 Return result
End Function
```

Then you should really access it like this: http://localhost:57851/docmgr/6202

Comment: I converted my code using your suggestion of using HttpResponseMessage and getting the content-type and stream from the database and it works wonderfully.  Many thanks!